# Spring Data Rest 2.4 doesn't work with {?page,size,sort} links

Tags: spring-data-rest

I've faced with the following problem:

Spring Data Rest version: org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.4.0.RELEASE

When i perform the query: http://localhost:8080/data/entities/ - the base query for my Rest servlet. 
It produces the links for all entities i have. The links has the following standard form:

```
"entityA": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/data/entities/entitiA{?page,size,sort}",
        "templated": true
    }
```

When i try to perform the generated link:

```
http://localhost:8080/data/entities/entitiA{?page,size,sort}
```

I have 404 NotFound exception.

But when i execute

```
http://localhost:8080/data/entities/entitiA
```

it works fine.

Do you have any ideas about it or could you suggest any solution to execute links in the format:

```
http://localhost:8080/data/entities/entitiA{?page,size,sort}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is worth to look at the documentation ;-)
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting

`{?page,size,sort}` is a template. It tells you which request parameters the resource supports. You are not supposed to use a templated link as it is in the response - you expand it first.

So a request like this should be working
`http://localhost:8080/cars/data/entities/entitiA?page=1&size=20`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now i can see, you are talking about following: "It’s also important to notice that the self and next URIs are, in fact, URItemplates."

But what about the previous version 2.2.1.RELEASE, why it works fine? I can perform requests with {?page,size,sort}.

Hmm.., that is interesting...I didn't find the same chapter in the documentation for the previous version: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/

It seems that is the feature of the new version.

Comment: Also, to be more accurate, i debugged the code, and found the problem in the org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.
public Resources<?> getCollectionResourceCompact(....)

I saw that the request variable has the following uri: /data/entities/entitiA{ , and if you will remove the curly bracket from request and perform 

http://localhost:8080/data/entities/entitiA?page,size,sort}  everything will be fine.

Comment: Maybe, you can suggest how to generate links without {?page,size,sort}?